# How to access user last connection IP address on profile

Tags: discussion, data-explorer, data-dump, data-analysis

I'm doing some work on the network analysis of a Stack Exchange community. I need the location of its users, but as you know, not everyone fills in the *Location* field.

I find the [Data.StackExchange]..Users table, but I don't know if the Id field is related with the AccountId from the community Users table. If it's not true, is there another way to get the last connection IP addresses of the users?

Comment: I would prefer Stack Exchange _not_ leak my location via IP address, thankyouverymuch.

Comment: @AlE. - we too would prefer not to leak *any* non public, personally identifying information of our users.

Comment: You _could_ always try hacking into their private database that probably does have IPs. (don't actually do that.)

Comment: You could train a neural network to estimate the location based on user contributions (the training set would be for the users that have filled in the location field). The style of English is a dead giveaway of where they are located.

Comment: Thanks @PeterMortesen. Great contribution. I would like to give your answer as the one that solved the issue

Answer (score 13):

No, the IP address of a user is not accessible through SEDE or the API, not even your own IP address. Luckily they have left that out.

Comment: so, the AccountId field is just for internal use, or can we access some more information of a user profile using another db schema ?

Comment: I guess that is the network account id. You could group accounts on several sites together using that.

Comment: It was a design decision - we do not divulge PII (Personally Identifiable Information), in particular not in the data dump.

Comment: Seems logical to me @Oded. You don't want to expose that in SEDE, maybe in the API on `/me`, but not very relevant in my opinion.

Comment: @san any reason you unaccepted my answer? Is there anything I  can help you with?

Comment: @PatrickHofman the OP finds the comment suggestion from Peter Mortensen about the neural network more interesting than your **NO**...

Comment: That explains it all. Thanks @rene